# R Subtract Rows

Tags: r, data.table

```
   library(data.table)
 data=data.frame(SCHOOL=c(1,1,2,2),
    GROUP=c(1,2,1,2),
    SCORE=c(5,2,8,9),
    WANT=c(3,NA,-1,NA))
```

I have 'data' and wish to subtract the 'SCORE' value such that for every 'SCHOOL' I calculate SCORE for GROUP 1 - GROUP 2; see 'WANT' variable for desired output thank you

---

---

```
   library(data.table)
 data=data.frame(SCHOOL=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
    GROUP=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
    SCORE=c(5,2,8,9,4,NA),
    WANT=c(3,NA,-1,NA,NA))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'SCHOOL', `order` the 'GROUP' in `i`, get the difference between 'SCORE', concatenate NA at the end and assign (`:=`) to create the 'WANT' in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[order(GROUP), WANT :=  c(SCORE[1]-SCORE[2], NA) , SCHOOL]
```

Comment: this is perfect thanks a bunch, what if you have an example where not all data are available..how is it possible to skip those ones? THANK YOU

Comment: @bvowe If you want to skip that group, use `setDT(data)[order(GROUP), WANT :=  if(.N <2) NA else c(SCORE[1]-SCORE[2], NA) , SCHOOL]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `shift` to subtract value from the next row.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[order(GROUP), WANT := SCORE - shift(SCORE, type = "lead"), SCHOOL]
data

#   SCHOOL GROUP SCORE WANT
#1:      1     1     5    3
#2:      1     2     2   NA
#3:      2     1     8   -1
#4:      2     2     9   NA
```

---

In `dplyr` we can use `lead` to do the same :

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
 arrange(SCHOOL, GROUP) %>%
 group_by(SCHOOL) %>%
 mutate(WANT = SCORE - lead(SCORE))
```